# Example of Zero-Divisors

Tags: ring-theory

I am working on the following problem:

> Find elements $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the ring $\mathbf{Z} \oplus \mathbf{Z} \oplus \mathbf{Z}$ such that $ab$, $ac$, and $bc$ are zero-divisors but $abc$ is not a zero-divisor.

The book suggests the answer $a=(1,1,0), b=(1,0,1), c=(0,1,1)$

This is confusing to me though because $ab=(1,0,0)$. The definition of zero divisor requires $ab=(0,0,0)$ when each $a,b\neq 0$, right?

Similarly according to the problem, $abc$ should equal some non-zero thing right? There's no way to achieve that with this triple.

Comment: Hint: $ab$ being a zero-divisor clearly implies $abc$ being either a zero-divisor or... what? (Read the definition of zero-divisor again. This problem almost qualifies as a trick question in my opinion.)

Comment: @Arthur Remove “almost”. If $ab$ is a zero divisor, then $d(ab)=0$ for some $d\ne0$. Then also $abc$ is a zero divisor if it is nonzero. So the only way $abc$ is not a zero divisor is that $abc=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you're checking that $ab$ is a zero divisor, which means finding $d \not = 0$ s.t. $(ab) \cdot d = 0$. This is achieved for $d=c$. You're not trying to prove that $ab = 0$.

For the problem not that we have $abc = 0$, so it can't be zero divisor, as the zero divisor is different from $0$ by definition.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing being a *zero divisor* with being *zero*. For instance, $(1,0,0) \cdot (0,0,1) = (0,0,0)$, even though neither $(1,0,0)$ nor $(0,0,1)$ are zero.